# XML schema & xml document not validating

Tags: xml, xsd, schema, xsd-validation, xmlschemaset

I was wondering if you could point out whats wrong with my schema? I have checked that my `XML` document is well formed using - http://www.utilities-online.info/xsdvalidation/#.VQkt1BCUfA4 - It's well formed. But when I check my `schema` against my `xml` document it will display a whole lot of erros. I don't really know what I'm doing wrong in my schema! If someone could give me a hand that would be great.

### grant.xml File:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE grant [
    <!ELEMENT grant (title, agency, department, summary, initiated, expires, coordinator)>
    <!ATTLIST grant grantNum ID #REQUIRED>
    <!ATTLIST grant funding (federal|state|local|private) #REQUIRED>

    <!ELEMENT title (#PCDATA)>
    <!ELEMENT agency (#PCDATA)>
    <!ELEMENT department (#PCDATA)>
    <!ELEMENT summary (#PCDATA)>
    <!ELEMENT initiated (#PCDATA)>
    <!ELEMENT expires (#PCDATA)>
    <!ELEMENT coordinator (#PCDATA)>


]>

<grant      xmlns="http://www.w3schools.com"
            xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"  
            xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.w3schools.com grant.xsd"
            grantNum="NIHCCC-4481-05" funding="federal">
<title>NIH Clinical Cancer Basic Research Grant</title>
<agency>National Institute of Health</agency>
<department>University Hospital Clinical Cancer Center</department>
<summary>
Basic NIH support funding for current and future Phase 1 through Phase 3 cancer
clinical trials.
</summary>
<initiated>2006-07-01</initiated>
<expires>2010-06-30</expires>
<coordinator>Alice Walters</coordinator>
</grant>
```

### grant.xsd File:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"> <!-- 1. root element for a schema -->


<!-- Elements -->
    <xs:element name='agency' type='xs:string' />
    <xs:element name='summary' type='xs:string' />
    <xs:element name='department' type='xs:string' />
    <xs:element name='summary' type='xs:date' />
    <xs:element name='initiated' type='xs:date' />
    <xs:element name='expires' type='xs:date' />
    <xs:element name='coordinator' type='xs:string' />

<!-- Attributes -->
    <xs:attribute name='grantNum' type='xs:grantNumFormat' />
    <xs:attribute name='funding' type='xs:fundingFormat' />


<!-- Simple Type -->
    <xs:simpleType name='grantNumFormat'>
        <xs:restriction base='xs:ID'>
            <xs:pattern value='Lu(6)-d(4)-d(2)' />
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>

    <xs:simpleType name='fundingFormat'>
        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
            <xs:enumeration value="male" />
            <xs:enumeration value="female" />
            <xs:enumeration value="all" />
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>


<!-- Complex Type -->

    <xs:element name="grant"> <!-- 4. declare the complex type -->
            <xs:complexType>
                <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element ref="agency" />
                    <xs:element ref="summary" />
                    <xs:element ref="department" />
                    <xs:element ref="summary" />
                    <xs:element ref="initiated" /> <!-- 7. can have many comments -->
                    <xs:element ref="expires" />
                    <xs:element ref='coordinator' />
                </xs:sequence>
                <xs:attribute ref="grantNum" use="required" /> <!-- 6. attribute specify the use -->
                <xs:attribute ref="funding" use="required" />
            </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

If I'm doing my schema wrong please let me know!

Comment: Why don't you first tell us if you really must be using both DTD and XSD.

Comment: You'd get more people prepared to look at this question if you told us what the validation errors were.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly (according to this validator : http://www.utilities-online.info/xsdvalidation/) : your xs file isn't well formed. you have to elements 'summary' declared, just declare that on time and reference it twice if needed. When you're using custom types which are in your xsd file, you cannot say that there are in the namespace, so remove `xs:` in `type='xs:grantNumFormat'` and in `type='xs:fundingFormat'`